# Inheritance of project (.vcproj) properties in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, project, solution, vcproj

My IDE is Visual Studio 2010. I have a solution (.sln) containing more than 100 Projects (.vcproj). The language is C++. The solution has two configurations: "Release" and "Debug". The solution has two Platforms "Win32" and "x64". I need to create a third configuration, let's call it "Release_and_PDB". "Release_and_PDB" should be equal to "Release" except in that it should generate the PDB files. In the future "Release_and_PDB" should be always equal to "Release" except in that it should generate the PDB files. I think I can do it in three steps:

1. Create a new Configuration.
2. Manually change every project property adding the path and name for the PDB (in Linker, Debugging, Generate Program Database file).
3. Ensure that a property change in the Release will also reflect the same change to the Release_and_PDB configuration

My questions:

a. Does Visual Studio have any facilities to get the step 2 done without the need of manually changing the properties of any (and every) project?

b. Does Visual Studio have any facilities for the inheritance of project properties to get step 3 done without the need to also manually change the property in Release_and_PDB?

Comment: Select all projects in the Solution Explorer window with Shift+Click.  Then Project + Properties.

Answer (score 1):

You go to configurations manager in the toolbar -> new -> copy settings from.

I think that's what you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what you suggest is covered in my step 1. What about the other steps?

Comment: @uvts_cvs oh ok. In that case, why do you need 2 configurations? Just have a debug and a release, and don't ship the .pdb files. No?

Comment: Generating the PDB is time consuming and does not fit very well with builds on developers computers.